# How can I run MS-DOS in real mode under Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista, ms-dos

I need to run a 16-bit diagnostic tool in real mode under Windows XP, Vista, or 7.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8):

Windows XP and later (Vista, 7) are based on the Windows NT kernel and don't rely on DOS, unlike Windows 3.1, 3.11, 95, 98, and ME.  Windows Me dropped real-mode DOS support.

Windows NT includes a NTVDM (NT Virtual DOS Machine) that emulates a 16-bit DOS mode for 32-bit but not 64-bit versions.

If you really need to run tools that rely upon low level BIOS and hardware interface calls in 16-bit mode, you need to boot into a DOS environment completely outside of Windows.

[FreeDOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDOS) an example of a separate 16-bit real mode DOS environment. You can install it into a separate partition, run it off of a live CD, or from a USB stick.

Comment: Or use a virtual machine? (Depending on what you are using the diagnostic tools for)

Comment: @MrStatic, the whole point is that the program needs access to the REAL hardware, not virtual.  If it were happy with virtual hardware it would run fine under Windows.

Comment: @psusi, where did you get that from? It doesn’t specifically say it’s a *hardware* diagnostic program.

Comment: @Synetech, because if it was happy running under a virtual machine, it would be happy running under the normal built in dos vm that windows has and uses to run dos programs, hence, the question would be moot.  Also a 16 bit *software* diagnostic tool would be utterly useless when you aren't running a 16 bit os.

Comment: *> It would be happy running under the normal built in dos vm that windows has and uses to run dos programs*   @psusi, unfortunately that’s not true. There are plenty of DOS software that won’t run correctly or at all in even XP’s NTVDM for one reason or another (vis 3D games).